# Intention action doesn't display window in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I've just upgraded my Ram and used new SSD hard, updated windows 10 and reinstalled last version of android studio and every thing was going very well until i found that alt+enter shortcut doesn't work and you know how this shortcut is important for android developers so i did some search but found no thing..

After a while i found that actually it does its job but the problem is that it doesn't display its window or popup on screen and i think it's some thing related to my intel card cause when i rotate screen the popup shows but then if i go back to default rotation and try nothing shows up !!!

[trying to perform intention action, nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfdfM.png)

[popup appears when rotating screen!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gedha.png)

also Alt+insert has the same behavior

Any one can help me with this problem?